# Installing MySQL so file

Tags: mysql, plugins

Probably an easy question, but I'm trying to install [sys_exec](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_sys/index.php#sys_exec) into MySQL. It contains an so file, along with a few other things.

Where do I place the .so file? I'm running Debian + MySQL5 
I've tried `/var/lib/mysql/`, `/usr/share/mysql` and `/usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql` which according to MySQL Docs is the location for libs/plugin directory. 
When I go to insert it into MySQL using the following query 
`CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS INT SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';`

{**edit**: original problem sorted}

Returns:

> Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so' (errno: 22 /etc/mysql/plugin/lib_mysqludf_sys.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied)

Yet permissions are set like so:

`drwxr-xrwx 2 root  root   4096 2010-08-19 08:10 .` 
`drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root   4096 2010-08-19 08:09 ..`
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 12896 2010-08-19 08:10 lib_mysqludf_sys.so`

Anyone able to offer assistance?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted, it had an sh file in there. Made sure I had libmysqlclient15-dev installed and had the appropriate permissions to the sh/makefile.